# Getting error code "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a cleverbot discord bot. I have put my token into the `superSecretBotTokenHere`, and the bot is running. But whenever I send my bot a `Dm`, the bot starts typing, then stops typing and I get this error code:

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

This is my code:

```
const Cleverbot = require("cleverbot-node");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const clbot = new Cleverbot;
 
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
    clbot.write(message.content, (response) => {
      message.channel.startTyping();
      setTimeout(() => {
        message.channel.send(response.output).catch(console.error);
        message.channel.stopTyping();
      }, Math.random() * (1 - 3) + 1 * 1000);
    });
  }
});
 
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});
 
client.login("superSecretBotTokenHere");
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that `response.output` is empty. Hence "cannot send an empty message". Check the value of `response.output` before you send it.

Comment: From looking at [`cleverbot-node`'s npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cleverbot-node), it seems that you forgot to call `Cleverbot#configure()`

Comment: @Lioness100 so how do I call it?

Comment: Look at the npm page I linked

Comment: @Lioness100 I looked in there and I am not sure what I am supposed to look for there. As I said I am VERY new to any sort of coding.

Comment: "API Key is now required [...] In order to add your key to your bot, you can use the configure method. API keys can be obtained from the [Cleverbot API Sign Up Page](http://cleverbot.com/api). [...] `cleverbot = new Cleverbot; cleverbot.configure({botapi: "IAMKEY"});`"

Comment: @Lioness100 Oh yeah I just realised they dont have free trials anymore. Thanks.